# Initializing C char array using curly braces, is it okay to omit null byte '\0'?

Tags: c, character-arrays

So I read that:

`char pattern[] = "ould";`

is basically the easier way of writing:

`char pattern[] = { 'o', 'u', 'l', 'd', '\0' };`

I understand that the null character `\0` marks the end of a string, but what if I write it like:

`char pattern[] = { 'o', 'u', 'l', 'd'};` (without the \0)

It still compiles.

Where would `pattern` without the `\0` cause problems, because it seems to be compile without warnings (`-Wall`)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you leave off the terminating zero, you no longer have a null terminated string, just an array of `char`, so passing it to any function that expects a string would be an error. E.g. `strlen`, as the source parameter to `strcpy`, as a `...` parameter to `printf` with a `%s` format specifier, etc.

Comment: Aah, so the `\0` makes the character array a C string? (new to C here)

Comment: @AA: Yes, in the C standard a _string_ is defined as a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character.

Comment: @A, exactly. An array is just a sequence of something, but you need to know the array length to work with it safely. For strings, the terminating `\0` is usually used instead, so you don't have to pass the length around. It's just a convention, but it is widely respected by lots of library functions, both in the standard library and third-party libraries.

Answer (score 3):

What's wrong with this behaviour? It is perfectly valid to have a char array without a '\0' on the end. Its just an array. The only reason the '\0' exists is to delimit the string. If you know what the length is, you don't need it!

Char arrays aren't special from other arrays. The only thing you need the '\0' for are the standard string functions.

Answer (score 2):

Its not a compiler warning, but a logical one. If you use `strcpy` without the `\0` you potentially could corrupt your stack.

Answer (score 2):

it wouldn't cause problems with the compiler, where it would cause problems is that many functions, e.g. `printf` assume that when you pass something in with the %s format specifier it will be '\0' terminated.

But if you are only passing that array into functions you write, or where you pass in the length of the array as a separate parameter and they all know how long it is it won't cause a problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
char string[] = "abcd"; /*is valid at the end is the \0, 5 chars were allocated*/

char str[3] = {'\0'}; /* all are \0 */

strncpy(str, string, 2); /*strcpy doesn't add \0*/

str[3] = '\0'; /* now is everything fine! */
```

Comment: ITYM `str[2] = '\0';`. str has enough space for 3 bytes and you're trying to set what would be its 4th byte to 0.

Comment: It's not enough to "give the idea". Please edit your answer so that it doesn't invoke undefined behavior, which is anything but "fine".

Answer (score 1):

It's a problem if ever you treat it as a string. For example, using strcmp, strcpy, printf. They all expect to find the null terminator, so will definitely encounter problems.

A plain old array of characters is OK as long as you're only ever treating it as an array of characters. e.g.

```
char c = pattern[2];
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course it compiles -- it's a valid C program.   The problems would occur if you tried to pass in your character array to a function expecting a null-terminated string (an array of characters ending with '\0').

Answer (score 1):

For example getting the length of the string will produce unpredictable results.
`strlen(pattern)`